# Do Knockdown texture walls and ceilings usually contain asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

My girlfriend recently has asked me to undertake some DIY work around her house for her parents. Now if have a respirator that protects from any dust or airborne hazardous material. Problem I’m encountering is that I suspect due to the age of the house (1955) that the textured walls will have asbestos. I’ve looked across different websites and there’s absolutely no information about asbestos being used in knockdown textured walls. Even google thinks I mean popcorn texture. I know what companies mainly used it but none mentioned Knockdown texture. Can someone with a bit more experience with this possibly help me out this this and is there a reason no one mentions Knockdown texture walls in regards to containing asbestos and just mentions popcorn ceilings?

Kind regards
Chris

Comment: If you have any doubt, get it tested.  With "vintage 1955" construction it's more than a remote possibility.  Asbestos that is in place is relatively safe but once you start disturbing it you liberate the dangerous fibers and you need more than the "garden variety" respirators that you might use while painting.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is it may have asbestos in the mud that was used for the knockdown texture if built prior to 1980.

Most earlier joint compounds did have levels of asbestos in them, I am not sure of the amount and I used to sand walls all the time in the 70’s and most of the time did not wear a mask, today any kind of sanding I use a dust mask we get smarter as we get older and realize we are not invincible. I would get the material tested to be sure as not all mud was made with asbestos.